# Ghost downvotes?

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, vote-count

On my phone I always use the responsive design; that might cause the bug. There’s a weird bug or something that causes the scores of deleted answers (and maybe deleted questions, and maybe non-deleted of both) to show as one point higher.

For example, on Politics, there is [this deleted answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/48452/24826). When I loaded the question a few minutes ago, the answer said it had a -3 score. However, looking at the vote counts, I saw that it has 4 downvotes and no upvotes ([the timeline concurs](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/48452/timeline)). When I reload the page, it shows the score as -4.

This has happened on other posts.

**What’s going on?**

Comment: When a post is deleted while it has a VLQ flag on it, Community casts an automatic downvote while validating the flag as helpful due to the deletion. I'd guess it's a race condition with the process for adding the downvote trying to update the score of the post at the same time the deletion process is trying to save deletion state to the same post. This has been a known issue for some time, it's just not one many people care about because the post is deleted.

Comment: @animuson huh, interesting. Why exactly does it cast the downvote?

Comment: There were several cases where due to the penalty for downvoting, people were using the flag in cases where they should have been downvoting. The flag was viewed as more or less what users were trying to indicate. Therefore, whenever a VLQ flag on an answer is marked helpful, the answer is automatically downvoted; also, deletion is one of many ways by which such flags can be automatically marked helpful.